# How can Ripley's K Function output in ModelBuilder be used as the search radius for Kernel Density analysis?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, kernel-density

I am using ArcGIS 10.3.1 (Basic license).

The first part of the model takes point data, runs it through Ripley's K Function tool, sorts the data in descending order by the DiffK column, and then uses "Get the Field Value." At this point I have generated a single value that represents a distance. All that works well, but I am not having any luck getting that generated distance to be used as the input for the Kernel Density search radius (model parameter) later in the same model.

I have tried making a model parameter variable for the Kernel Density tool, but I cannot connect the search radius model parameter to the distance value.

Any thoughts on how to use a model-generated single value as input for a Kernel Density model parameter (search radius)?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example model I have put together.

[image]

When adding the parameters for the "Get Field Value" make sure the Data Type is one that is numeric. (Double was the only I could find)

[image]

The output from the "Get Field Value" tool should now show as "Value" in the dropdown for "Search radius".

[image]